# Unable to modify BIOS. Unable to boot USB

Tags: windows, lenovo, bios, grub-efi

I used to have dual boot system: Ubuntu and Windows. Recently, something wrong happend to my Ubuntu. I tried to fixed, but nothing helped. I tried to boot usb with Ubuntu, but turns out that I have common [problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147) with my laptop. So i tried to delete all, wich connected to Ubuntu. I formatted the disk with linux. Tried to delete folder with Ubuntu in EFI folder (but it still can't be deleted). I tried to restore my Windows, reinstall Ubuntu different ways (throw USB, throw Windows). I tried to reinstall Windows.

So right now I have working Windows, but I can't change BIOS and install new OS. 
Can somebody help me to work out this?

UPD: On link above there is a solution using Ubuntu. But I have no opportunity to boot Ubuntu... Probably somebody knows any way?

Comment: did u try disabling secure boot?

Comment: yes( no changes

Comment: you need update your bios from official drivers page, if you have win10 there is a easy way to do that

Comment: I actually tried... But when i restart, there nothing happens

Comment: @EugeneSirkiza Do a full shut down (NOT just a 'restart' option in the system) and then turn it back on.  A lot of systems have a 'warm reboot' which won't pick up the firmware update.  (Also make sure to disable Fast Boot in Windows for the BIOS update)

Comment: When my pc turns on, it tries to launch Ubuntu, which is uninstalled. And i can't change the order, as i mentioned. So any attempts to launch windows even first are useless(